# How can I call one jersey service from another service in java ? Also how can I inject HttpServletRequest object inside my AuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

While injecting HttpServletRequest object in Jersey 2.0 I get this exception -> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope`.

I tried injecting HttpServletRequest object in AuthenticationFIlter for getting client IP address, but it failed with above exception, But the same code worked in jersey 2.2.3 api perfectly.

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public String getClientIP(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Filter called.");
        clientIP = new AuthFilter().getClientIP(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Tried injecting HttpServletRequest object in AuthenticationFIlter for getting client IP address, but it failed with above exception, But the same code worked in jersey 2.2.3 api perfectly.

Comment: That's not Jersey 2.x (`org.glassfish.jersey`). That's Jersey 1.x (`com.sun.jersey.spi`). Are you sure you want to use Jersey 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. You mentioned you are using *Jersey 2.x*, but you are actually using the *Jersey 1.x* API.

*Jersey 1.x* and *Jersey 2.x* use different package names:

- Jersey 1.x: `com.sun.jersey`
- Jersey 2.x: `org.glassfish.jersey`

In Jersey 2.x, you would have the following:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        ...
    }
}
```

---

The [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) interface is in the [`javax.ws.rs.container`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/package-summary.html) package, which is part of the JAX-RS 2.0 API. And Jersey 2.x is the reference implementation of the JAX-RS 2.0 specification.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But still with jersey 2.0 its throwing me following exception SEVERE: Servlet /test threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:149)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java

Comment: Even tomcat is not starting after injecting @Context HttpServletRequest request